# Missing or incorrect data in Oracle EBS backend query (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I am learning Oracle E-Business Suite. Using an SQL Query, I want to fetch all items (`ASSEMBLY_ITEM`) which are `BOM` enabled and whose job creation date is within the last 3 years. The query I have written gives me the desired results but somehow, the component item list (`COMPONENT_ITEM`) has incomplete data or (`Null`) for some items. For example, some items which I know has 5 components but in the SQL query output, that same item shows up as having a single component. I am verifying the data from the Oracle Apps frontend part.
Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BOM.BILL_SEQUENCE_ID,
  MSI.ORGANIZATION_ID,
  MSI.SEGMENT1 ASSEMBLY_ITEM,
  (SELECT SEGMENT1
  FROM MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
  WHERE INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=BIC.COMPONENT_ITEM_ID
  AND rownum             =1
  ) "COMPONENT_ITEM"
FROM BOM_OPERATIONAL_ROUTINGS BOR,
  BOM_BILL_OF_MATERIALS BOM,
  BOM_INVENTORY_COMPONENTS BIC,
  MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B MSI
WHERE BOR.ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID      = BOM.ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID
AND BOR.ORGANIZATION_ID         = BOM.ORGANIZATION_ID
AND BOM.BILL_SEQUENCE_ID        = BIC.BILL_SEQUENCE_ID(+)
AND BOM.ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID        = MSI.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID(+)
AND BOM.ORGANIZATION_ID         = MSI.ORGANIZATION_ID
AND MSI.ORGANIZATION_ID        IN (203, 204, 328)
AND MSI.BOM_ENABLED_FLAG        = 'Y'
AND NVL (MSI.ENABLED_FLAG, 'X') = 'Y'
AND BOR.ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID       IN
  (SELECT DISTINCT PRIMARY_ITEM_ID
  FROM WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS WDJ
  WHERE BOR.ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID = WDJ.PRIMARY_ITEM_ID
  AND WDJ.CREATION_DATE     >= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12*3)
  )
```

My query should return unique assembly items, each of which may have one or more components.

Ideally, I should be getting , all unique assembly items along with their component items. I have achieved this by removing the join on `BOM.BILL_SEQUENCE_ID = BIC.BILL_SEQUENCE_ID (+)`, and also removing the semi-join at the end of the query, the "`AND BOR.ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID IN`" part, which essentially filters the results since the last 3 years.

The join part isn't the real issue. Is there any way to filter the result based on items created in the last 3 years, using something other than this method?
What am I missing here?

Comment: General comments: Please replace the implicit joins with _explicit_ joins.  And also if you could include some sample data and expected output that would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you could do better here.

First, use `ANSI JOINS`.  I see at least some of your problems are due to incorrect attempt as LEFT OUTER joins.  Using the `ANSI` syntax will help you avoid such problems.

Second, don't use `DISTINCT` unless you understand WHY it is necessary.  It should not be necessary to write the query you say you want.

Third, You don't need to join `BOM_OPERATIONAL_ROUTINGS` -- you're not using it for anything (unless you are trying to use it as a filter -- to limit to `BOM`s that have a routing?)

Fourth, use `EXISTS` instead of `IN`.  Oracle's optimizer is mostly smart enough to protect you from the performance penalty that `IN` would have hit you with in the past.  Nevertheless, `EXISTS` better represents your intent (imo) and places less reliance on the optimizer being smart.

Finally, the `ROWNUM=1` to get the component item isn't necessary. You just need to limit by `ORGANIZATION_ID` as well.

Putting it all together, the following query should be pretty close to what you are looking for:

```
SELECT bom.bill_sequence_id,
       bom.organization_id,
       msi.segment1 assembly_item_id,
       bic.operation_seq_num,
       msic.segment1 component_item
FROM   bom_bill_of_materials bom
       LEFT JOIN mtl_system_items msi
         ON msi.organization_id = bom.organization_id
         AND msi.inventory_item_id = bom.assembly_item_id
         AND msi.enabled_flag = 'Y'
         AND msi.bom_enabled_flag = 'Y'
       LEFT JOIN bom_inventory_components bic ON bic.bill_sequence_id = bom.common_bill_sequence_id
       LEFT JOIN mtl_system_items msic
         ON msic.organization_id = bom.organization_id
         AND msic.inventory_item_id = bic.component_item_id
WHERE  bom.organization_id IN (203, 204, 328)
AND    EXISTS
         (SELECT 'job for item in last 3 years'
          FROM   wip_discrete_jobs wdj
          WHERE  wdj.primary_item_id = bom.assembly_item_id
          AND    wdj.creation_date >= ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -36))
-- Unless you are loading a table with this, you may want to ORDER BY...
;
```

Comment: Running your query, I see that the data fetched has COMPONENT_ITEM for only first 23 records (or only for ORGANIZATION_ID = 328). Although the total record count is over 500, the remaining records have Null data for OPERATION_SEQ_NUMBER and COMPONENT_ITEM_ID. 
I'm curious, why did you select OPERATION_SEQ_NUMBER? Does that in any way indicate the item's existence in the BIC table?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly why.  `OPERATION_SEQ_NUM` is not nullable.

Comment: Because you are using `LEFT JOIN` to get the assembly items (from `MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS` and item that is no longer enabled or BOM enabled will show up with `NULL` `assembly_item_id`.  Is that what you are seeing?  Or are you seeing non-null assembly_item_ids with NULL component_items?

Comment: Non null assembly item ID but with null component item list. The organizations ID is also correct

Comment: Query the BOM for that assembly item / organization ID using the Forms front-end.  Do you see data?

Comment: Yes, I have checked. There are Assembly Items with component items for the other organizations also

Comment: In that case, I would guess then that your bill of materials has been "commoned",  That means you don't actually have BOM_INVENTORY_COMPONENT records in each organization.  Rather, the BOM refers to the component list from another organization.  That will require revisions to the query.  I'll send something in a bit.

Comment: Update the join condition between `BIC` and `BOM` to this: `LEFT JOIN bom_inventory_components bic ON bic.bill_sequence_id = bom.common_bill_sequence_id`.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yes Matthew, you are absolutely correct. The items whose components aren't present in the query output, shows me a warning in the front end stating something along the lines of 'Can't view common components'. I really appreciate your efforts!

Comment: Sure Matthew, but I can't run the query tonight though because I don't have a laptop with me right now. I'll post back in a few hours. Thanks, again.

Comment: Replying to your original answer, seeing your query, I now realize why the DISTINCT wasn't necessary, and I'll try to use EXISTS instead of IN and also ANSI joins from now on (I read up about them here). As for joining with routings, I did that to filter the results from BOM which have a routing. Where do you suggest I use it?
Also, can you please explain why I don't need ROWNUM = 1 but only need to limit by ORGANIZATION_ID for the components? I didn't quite get that part.
I still need to fetch the COMPONENT_QUANTITY in the original query. I'll try that on my own.

Comment: "ROWNUM" answer: because INVENTORY_ITEM_ID + ORGANIZATION_ID is the primary key for MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS, so if you specify both, you will get (at most) one row out for each row you are joining to it.

Comment: "routings" answer: if you can specify the routing uniquely (i.e., join on all values of its primary key), then you can put it back in the join.  If you cannot specify all primary key fields, then use an EXISTS.

Comment: I tried searching for discrete jobs for a particular assembly item by searching against the ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID in the Find Discrete Jobs forms, but the item ID is not found for that list of values. I also searched for the item in the WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS table, but it's not present there too. Why does this item show up in the query results? I haven't found any other item with this issue though.

Comment: First of all, the online forms do not let you query by item ids.  They are internal primary keys.  Get the `SEGMENT1` value for the item id from `MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS`.  Regarding searching the `WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS` table, it must be there or the `EXISTS` filter in the query would have excluded it.

Comment: I searched the Discrete Jobs form with the Assembly Item IDs for other items, and they return results as expected.  Why not just for this item? I also figured out that the Forms throws that issue only for a particular organisation. Returns expected results for other organizations having the same item.

Comment: I would recommend putting together a simple test case and posting another question.  Like post your main query that returns the item ID passing the EXISTS filter, then post another query showing that item ID is not in the table.  Sounds impossible, but a complete post would help people help you.  One UNLIKELY possibility is that you have a corrupt index on WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS, causing it to report back a hit for a row that doesn't actually exist in the table (assuming the EXISTS filter used that index in lieu of the table).

Comment: I tinkered a bit and figured out that the Discrete Jobs table doesn't have that item for that particular organisation. So, I just added WDJ.ORGANIZATION_ID = BOM.ORGANIZATION_ID to the EXISTS filter.

Comment: I see that this query fetches ALL components, but what if I want only the components that are still available for future use? I tried adding a filter for bic.disable_date > sysdate but then it returns NULL for component items also.

Comment: Did you add the `bic.disable_date` condition to the `LEFT JOIN`?  Also, you'd need it to be `nvl(bic.disable_date, SYSDATE+1) > SYSDATE`, or something like that, because anything with no disable date is active.  Also, you need to check the start date too, since some components may not yet be active (if you do that at your site and if you care).